# Как можно проверить переменную типа char на "пустоту"

Tags: c#

Допустим, есть массив `char[] board;`, в данном случае также есть список `List<int> result = new List<int>();`
И есть цикл, который перебирает данный массив и если элемент с индексом i данного массива пустой, то он добавляется в список result. Но как реализовать проверку, на то что элемент действительно пустой? Если попробывать, как сделал я в коде ниже, то выдает ошибку на проверке `Empty character literal`. Если, заменить проверку  на `if (board[i] == 0) {...}`, то в список добавляется только элемент с индексом 0, а если сделать вот так `if (board[i] == null) {...}`, то вообще ничего не добавляется. Как проверить элементы массива char на пустоту?(

```
for (int i = 0; i < board.Length; i++)
{
    if (board[i] == '')
    {
        result.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Что в Вашем понимании «пустой символ»? Ибо пишете Вы какие-то странные вещи

Comment: Для переменных типа string можно сделать проверку на "пустоту" вот так : `string a = " a "; if (a == "") {...}` Как сделать такую же проверку на "пустоту" у переменных типа char, если `char a = '1'; if (a == '') {...}` выдает ошибку.

Comment: Возможно вы хотите `if ( a == '\0')`, но формально "пустых" char не бывает, они не имеют null значения,а \0 - это всего лишь один из многих непечатных символов.

Answer (score 4):

char в C# - это value type, он не может иметь пустое значение, поэтому такая проверка не имеет смысла. Неинициализированная переменная типа char содержит его значение по умолчанию (символ `\0`). Если вам нужен тип, который может хранить либо символ, либо специальное пустое значение, смотрите в сторону [Nullable types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)

Comment: Хорошо, вот скриншот. Чему в данном случае равняется char у первого элемента массива? Там нету пробелов, нету ничего. https://imgur.com/a/ycyt0zg

Comment: @JediMan4ik, в данном случае это строка нулевой длины и у нее нет первого символа. Вы не сможете его получить, `myString[0]` бросит исключение.

Comment: в данном случае, это просто поле (UI элемент) в который можно вписать любой символ char. Строки тут не причем. Мне нужно сделать проверку, если моя переменная char действительно такая "пустая", как на картинке, значит ...

Comment: @JediMan4ik скриншот мало о чем говорит, дайте больше контекста. Если WPF, то покажите разметку.

Comment: @JediMan4ik в текстбоксе значение - это строка. Если вы как-то получаете из пустой строки (значения текстбокса) char - значит в вашем коде преобразования строки в char и принимается решение - что вернуть в случае пустой строки, и что считать "пустым" символом